# Different output when calling toString on the same StringBuilder instance

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I was testing around Strings, and I came up with below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("Cuba");
    String str1 = sb1.toString();
    // n1
    System.out.println(str1 == str2);
}
```

On `n1` if I place:

```
String str2 = sb1.toString();
```

I get `false`. However if I place:

```
String str2 = str1;
```

I get `true`.

I am not sure why this is happening: both codes are referring to the same instance, therefore, both output must be `true`.

Any idea why both output differ? I know how to compare Strings, I am just curious about the reason why the result differ.

Comment: I know how to compare Strings. Just curious about the reason why they differ.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't mean to offend you.

Comment: I don't feel like that :)

Answer (score 6):

This is the code of [`StringBuilder.toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.toString%28%29) in OpenJDK 8u40:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

so it's returning a new String everytime you invoke it.

When you set `str2 = str1`, they are the same instance so `==` returns `true`. However, when you set `str2 = sb1.toString()`, it gets set to a new String (having the same content), so `==` returns `false`.

This is actually specified in [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString--) Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Returns a string representing the data in this sequence. **A new String object is allocated** and initialized to contain the character sequence currently represented by this object. This String is then returned. Subsequent changes to this sequence do not affect the contents of the String.

Note that you shouldn't be using `==` to compare `String`s to begin with (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1743880)).